# How can one application consume (delete) lines from a text file while while another is writing them?

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I have the situation I would like two C++ applications to run on Windows. One is writing lines to a file, the other is removing them - effectively using a file as a producer/consumer pattern.

## Concept

### Producer

```
fp = openFile(path,writeFlags);
while(!stop)
{
 writeLineToFileAndFlush(fp,getNextLine());
}
```

### Consumer

```
fp = openFile(path, readWriteFlags);
while(!(stop || eof))
{
 txt = removeLineFromFile(fp); //read and delete the line
 process(txt);
}
```

This is conceptual only, because I am fairly sure on Windows that C/C++ doesn't allow you to delete from the start of a file like this i.e. `removeLineFromFile()` isn't really possible.

So how can I achieve my goal, in such a way that the Producer can continue to write to the file ignorant of what the Consumer is doing? In a perfect world the Producer would not even be aware the Consumer exists but I am not certain there are any file writing modes that allow that?

My thoughts so far run along the line of the Consumer repeatedly taking copies of the file and deleting the original, so the Producer keeps re-creating the file. In other words:

## Possible Design(?)

### Producer (unchanged)

```
fp = openFile(path,writeFlags);
while(!stop)
{
 writeLineToFileAndFlush(getNextLine());
}
```

### Consumer (modified)

```
while(!stop)
{
 copyFile(path,tempPath);
 eraseFile(path); //needs to not stop Producer writing to the now-empty file
 fp = openFile(tempPath, readWriteFlags);
 while(!eof)
 {
   txt = readLineFromFile(fp);
   process(txt);
 }
 deleteFile(tempPath);
}
```

Is this a workable/reasonable approach? If so, how do I do it in such a way the Producer can continue to work while the file it is writing to keeps being removed? If not, how might I achieve the goal which is to avoid any IPC in which the Producer must listen for the Consumer? It is a design restriction that the Consumer cannot call in or otherwise interact with the Producer - it must only listen in some sense.

Comment: Short answer: don't do that. Use mechanisms that designed for intraprocess communication.

Comment: The basis is that files are streaming devices.  You can't delete stuff in files, but you can overwrite the contents.  The common method for deletion is to write the old file contents to a new file, **except** the contents you want deleted.

Comment: Must you use files? Can you use pipes instead?

Comment: Looks like you are implementing *double buffering*, using a *single* file.  I recommend that one thread write to a file, until finished, then start on a second file.  The "read" thread will then start processing the first file (and can delete the file upon reaching the end).  My recommendation is one thread per file. You really don't want the threads clashing on a single file, gets ugly fast.

Comment: @Slava it is specifically desired to avoid coupling the two applications.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't understand your overwriting methodology - sort of see the shape of what you're meaning but not how it works. Could you expand in an answer?

Comment: @Omry I know nothing about pipes but if it can match the general concept and the Producer can simply throw data into the pipe and not care what happens, probably? I'm happy to see an answer showing how that could replace my ugly 'file buffer' :)

Comment: My methodology only overwrites to reuse files.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-client